# How to POST an image file with jQuery that is already saved on the server?

Tags: jquery

I see many tutorials for how to AJAX POST images using file inputs, but nothing about how to include images that are already saved in a directory on the sending server.

I'm using Meteor, so can only use Javascript to send the image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can send a image name in hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="myimage" value="imagename.jpg">

<script>
    var image = $('[name="myimage"]').val();
</script>
```

Comment: I need to send the image file, not the image name

Comment: if the image already on server, why you clone that? just more space on hd, you can save the name of image, to me make more sense

Comment: They are two different servers

Comment: you cant set content of "file" input field, maybe via php curl you can transfer between servers....